# Does holes in indexes impact somehow the database?

Tags: mysql, database, optimization

When creating a new index it seems that people try to avoid holes inside it, and usually use auto-incrementation. But why? What the reasons behind that? Maintenance? Security? Or simply not beautifull?
Because in my case, I'm suppose to create a book catalog database and for consistency reasons I would like to make sure that the index of the "book" table matches the fragment of the ISBN number corresponding to the publication number of the 1st edition of the book at this publisher.
However some reissues have their own ISBN but won't be counted as a book entity in itself and so will create holes (data of reissues will be merged with 1st edition data).

I use MySQL 5.7.23 with phpMyAdmin.

Here the view from the junction of the tables "Book" and "ISBN" I aim

```
num_book | ISBN
--------------------------------
1        | XXX-X-XXXXXX-1-X
         | XXX-X-XXXXXX-5-X
         | XXX-X-XXXXXX-9-X
         | XXX-X-XXXXXX-14-X
2        | XXX-X-XXXXXX-2-X
3        | XXX-X-XXXXXX-3-X
         | XXX-X-XXXXXX-6-X
         | XXX-X-XXXXXX-8-X
4        | XXX-X-XXXXXX-4-X
7        | XXX-X-XXXXXX-7-X
         | XXX-X-XXXXXX-13-X
10       | XXX-X-XXXXXX-10-X
11       | XXX-X-XXXXXX-11-X
12       | XXX-X-XXXXXX-12-X
15       | XXX-X-XXXXXX-15-X
```

I intend to use "**num_block**" with these intentional holes as primary key of the table book and then join with ISBN table.
The index numbers will remain increasing but wouldn't necessarily be successive (i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 10, 11, 12, 15)
Should I worry about that and why ?

Thanks by advance for your attention.

Edit : Oups as *scaisEdge* said, forgot can't start index with 0, corrected.
More clarifications & disambiguations about explanations and the sketch (add legend) : it's not the same table a but a view from the join of two tables (books and ISBN), so "num_book" value are unique but can be bind to severals "ISBN".

Comment: a primary key must be unique by definition    .. (and not null)  ... if num_book is your primary key you can't assign  null value or duplicate . value

Comment: @scaisEdge Thanks a lot, I put 0 cause because the 1st publication is n°0 ; I was almost sure it was impossible, but I still slipped the error to get a confirmation of that impossibility (done).
I clarified the explanations and the sketch because as it was presented, we could believe that it belonged to the same tables. But this is the view from a junction between two different tables. It's my fault, I used the wrong terms.

Comment: Auto-increment `int` indexes are faster because entries are small (4 bytes) so you can fit more entries per (2K) IO page. Auto-increment doesn't have holes, but that's not relevent to performance, only an artifact of convenience. See [surrogate key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key). Don't worry - just use your natural data. "Holes" are irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are referring to a few different concepts all at the same time.

There is a difference between a primary key and an index.

A primary key is a logical concept - it provides the unique, unchanging reference to a row in your table. As other entities refer to the primary key, it may not be null.

An index is a physical concept - it's a way for the database to look up entries in that column. You can specify that an index is not null, and unique.

The usual way to physically implement the logical concept of primary key is through a unique, not-null index.

The next question is how to assign the primary key; there are two candidates: natural keys reflect an entity in the problem domain, and surrogate keys are assigned automagically by the database.

In practice, there are very few natural keys (guaranteed unique, not null, unchanging) - I don't know enough about how ISBNs are assigned to have an opinion whether they are suitable. But I've seen problems with social security numbers (they get entered incorrectly into the system), phone numbers (people change their phone number), etc.

Surrogate keys are assigned by the database engine. They are often auto-incrementing integers, but they can also be UUIDs - as long as they are guaranteed unique and not null. The reason auto-incrementing integers are popular is for a couple of reasons.

Many primary keys are implemented using clustered indexes. A clustered index affects the order in which data is stored on disk, so if you have a clustered index, inserting record with ID 1 after you've written record with ID 1000 means re-ordering the data on disk, which is expensive.

Gaps are not really a problem - as long as you're inserting sequentially.

However...this logic is from the 1980s. Back then, a clustered index was notably faster than a non-clustered index. On modern hardware, that's not true in most circumstances.

So, there is no obvious reason why your scheme for assigning primary keys would be a problem as long as you are confident about the way ISBNs are assigned.

Comment: Thank you a lot. The question was awkwardly asked but you dissipated my concerns.